# Looking for some simple webcam software

Tags: webcam, source

It seems that uvccapture might meet my need for a simple webcam application.  However, trying to build it "out of the box", I get this bewildering collection ...

```
gcc -std=gnu99 -O2 -DLINUX -DVERSION=\"0.5-ac1\" -Wall -std=gnu99 -O2 -DLINUX -DVERSION=\"0.5-ac1\" -Wall  -c -o uvccapture.o uvccapture.c
In file included from uvccapture.c:36:0:
v4l2uvc.h:44:26: error: field ‘cap’ has incomplete type
v4l2uvc.h:45:22: error: field ‘fmt’ has incomplete type
v4l2uvc.h:46:22: error: field ‘buf’ has incomplete type
v4l2uvc.h:47:30: error: field ‘rb’ has incomplete type
uvccapture.c: In function ‘main’:
uvccapture.c:186:16: error: ‘V4L2_PIX_FMT_MJPEG’ undeclared (first use in this function)
uvccapture.c:186:16: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
uvccapture.c:239:16: error: ‘V4L2_PIX_FMT_YUYV’ undeclared (first use in this function)
uvccapture.c:313:30: error: ‘V4L2_CID_BRIGHTNESS’ undeclared (first use in this function)
uvccapture.c:314:30: error: ‘V4L2_CID_CONTRAST’ undeclared (first use in this function)
uvccapture.c:315:30: error: ‘V4L2_CID_SATURATION’ undeclared (first use in this function)
uvccapture.c:316:30: error: ‘V4L2_CID_GAIN’ undeclared (first use in this function)
```

Answer (score 2):

`Cheese` is a popular web cam app for Ubuntu, that should be what you need

```
sudo apt-get install cheese
```

[image]

There is also Camorama

```
sudo apt-get install camorama
```

[image]

As well as `guvcview`

```
sudo apt-get install guvcview
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, I checked the basic operation of the camera with cheese, but I need source code in order to include the camera in a comlex application.

Comment: You want the source code for cheese?

Comment: Well, what I'm really looking for is the simplest possible source code that just gets an image from the camera.  Because these three things include a GUI, the source code gets horrible; I quit after hours of package installs trying to get QtCam source.  That's why I went to uvccapture, and am frustrated that I can't compile it.

Comment: Why must you build it? it is in the default repo `sudo apt-get install uvccapture`

Comment: Mark, thanks for being so patient with me.  I am making a large networking demo and want to include as part of that the ability to get an image from the webcam and broadcast it.  So I need to know how to fetch an image from the camera in my own program.

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit confused here, you want to build your own program to take pictures, based off of the uvccapture source code?

Comment: Exactly - the end result will be chopping pieces out of uvccapture.  Happy to give credit to the original author(s)

Comment: Ok I think you should open a new question, I am not a programmer so am limited in the ways I can help with this. When you ask the question you should ask "How can I add the photo capture ability from uvccapture to my program", of course manipulate this to your liking, in your question, talk abut your application and ask what parts of `uvccapture` you must appropriate. As this question stands it is not clear this is your issue, it seems you just want some software. You may actually get better help at stack overflow, that is a site about programming. http://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Good luck :)...